# return not working in call to service inside a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

**Overview**

I'm learning Angular and Jhipster i need to get the name of a user
in the console is showing it just right but not really returning the value to the variable a I need

this is the function

```
nombreResponsable(id){

    this.userService.findById(id).subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<IUser>) => { 
            console.log(res.body.login);
            return res.body.login;
        },
        (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    );

}
```

and this is the call to the function

```
cargarActividades(id, meta, estrategia, id_meta) {
        this.activiadesDespliegueService.findByEstrategia(id).subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IActividadesDespliegue[]>) => {
                this.actividadesDespliegues = res.body;

                this.actividadesDespliegues.forEach(key => {

                    var responsable = this.nombreResponsable(key.responsableId); 
                    console.log(responsable);
                    //here is where i get null 
                    var datosActividad = {
                        meta: meta,
                        id: key.id,
                        estrategia: estrategia,
                        actividad: key.nombre,
                        fecha: key.fechaCumpliniento,
                        responsable: responsable,
                        puntacion: key.puntacion
                    };
                    this.cargarEvaluaciones(key.id);
                    this.actividadesDespliegueEstrategico.push(datosActividad);

                    this.listaDeMetas[id_meta].puntos = this.listaDeMetas[id_meta].puntos + key.puntacion;
                });
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
    }
```

in the console I see this:

```
 [Log] undefined (x2)
 [Log] admin
 [Log] cordinador
```

**My thoughts**

like I say im learning but I think this work in a similar way that Ajax on javascript or maybe its not the right sintaxis.

**Questions**

- Right way to get my data
- Is a better way to do it? im open to suggestion

**Notes**

- I'm really new on Angular, TypeScript, and Jhipster.
- Please if I missed something important, let me know on the comment and I will added to the question.

Comment: Looks like you're not returning the observable in your service function.

Comment: @EddiePaz sorry where I should get the observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` due to the asynchronous behaviour of observables.

The method `nombreResponsable(id)` calls the `this.userService.findById(id)` when called. Considering that it is returning an observable, it surely is asynchronous.

Hence in you end up with `undefined` in your component code when calling:

```
var responsable = this.nombreResponsable(key.responsableId); 
                    console.log(responsable);
                    //here is where i get null
```

A simple fix would be to subscribe to the observable returned by the `nombreResponsable` method in your component.

> Or even better use the async/await syntax. It makes it more readable.

For example:

```
// mark this method async
async nombreResponsable(id){
    try {
        const res = await this.userService.findById(id).toPromise();
        return res.body.login;
    } catch (e) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Then in your component mark calling method also async to use await:

```
async cargarActividades(id, meta, estrategia, id_meta) {
        this.activiadesDespliegueService.findByEstrategia(id).subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IActividadesDespliegue[]>) => {
                this.actividadesDespliegues = res.body;

                this.actividadesDespliegues.forEach(key => {
                    // use await to wait for the response and then execute further.
                    var responsable = await this.nombreResponsable(key.responsableId); 
                    console.log(responsable);
                    //here is where i get null 
                    var datosActividad = {
                        meta: meta,
                        id: key.id,
                        estrategia: estrategia,
                        actividad: key.nombre,
                        fecha: key.fechaCumpliniento,
                        responsable: responsable,
                        puntacion: key.puntacion
                    };
                    this.cargarEvaluaciones(key.id);
                    this.actividadesDespliegueEstrategico.push(datosActividad);

                    this.listaDeMetas[id_meta].puntos = this.listaDeMetas[id_meta].puntos + key.puntacion;
                });
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
    }
```

Comment: thank you! that solve my problem I was looking for he await and async, but don't find out a good example and its a little hard to learn all the concepts, thanks for the explain and the example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
nombreResponsable(id){

let data = this.userService.findById(id).subscribe(
    (res: HttpResponse<IUser>) => { 
        console.log(res.body.login);
        return res.body.login;
    },
    (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
); }
```

Comment: im getting this but not what I looking for 
`_parent: null

_parents: null

_subscriptions: null

closed: true

destination: SafeSubscriber {closed: true, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}

isStopped: true

syncErrorThrowable: true

syncErrorThrown: false

syncErrorValue: null`